# Access to a parent record in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new to Rails, so it may be a very silly question, but I spent a lot of time googling around and still havent figured it out.
I've created these scaffolds:

```
rails g scaffold Course coursename:string program:string
rails g scaffold Unit unitname:string daybegins:integer durationdays:integer course:references
```

And my models are:

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :coursename, presence: true, :uniqueness => {:case_sensitive => false}
  has_many :units
end

class Unit < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
end
```

How do I access attribures of my parent record (Course) in my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `.course`. So if you were in rails console and wanted to find the course for unit number 1 (or whatever unit you choose), it would look like: .

```
unit = Unit.find(1)
unit.course # will display the course for unit 1
unit.course.coursename # will display the course name for unit 1
```

Comment: Thanks! unit.course.coursename was the first thing I tried, however if was failing. It appeared that there was an invalid data(empty value) and nil object returned due to that. Your example worked for me in the console and I managed to fix the problem.